# How to find number of ways

Tags: string, depth-first-search, backtracking

Given a string s = "-------" of length 7 , and an infinite characters ranging from a-z, find number of ways to fill the string such that character a comes at most x times, b comes at most y times.

I tried Dfs + backtracking but missing some cases.

Comment: Please share your DFS+backtracking code, and make it runnable with the example input that reproduces the issue ("missing some cases"). Focus your question on that.

Comment: Also, what does "fill the string" mean? Does it mean that the hyphens need to be all *replaced*? Are the strings to count all to be 7 characters long, and should they not contain any hyphens?

Comment: By saying "cases", this means that this comes from some "competitive coding" website. Can you please provide some code and specify if it was a wrong answer, a time limit exceeded, or a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your solution ideas should solve the problem correctly. DFS and backtracking could do the work properly since you eliminate the results with more letters of a than x or more letters of b than y.

You can simply create a check function:

```
bool checkString(string str, char a, char b, int x, int y) { // all parameters
    int numOfA = 0, numOfB = 0; //initialize counters
    for (char x : str) { // start a loop
        if (x == a) { numOfA++; } // increment accordingly
        else if (x == b) { numOfB++; } // increment accordingly
    }
    if (a > x || b > y) { return false; } // if too many letters of a or b, return false
    return true;
}
```

And also add in another simple DFS:

```
void dfs(int currentIndex, string currentString) { // new function
    if (currentIndex > 6) { // if string is complete, decide whether or not to output it
        if (checkString(currentString, char1, char2, int1, int2)) {
            cout << currentString << '\n'; // careful: this is hundreds of millions of lines of all possible strings derived from the original total of 26^7, or 8,031,810,176 after shaving off some with the check function
        }
        return; // no more processing
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { // run all possible characters
        currentString[currentIndex] = ((char) ('a' + i));
        dfs(currentIndex + 1, currentString); // next round
    }
}
```

However, there would clearly be a significant timing issue since this strategy runs 26 letters 7 times, and then for each result, goes through the string, which is already O(n), to count the number of times the characters a and b appear. That would add up to 26 to the 7th power * 7 calculations, which can be a little slow (That's 56,222,671,232 calculations just from the algorithm there!). Worse, the outputting process for each of these results take time too.

If that does not prove to be an issue, you have a solution now.

Here is an [online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/PAcWYq8tX), or access the code below at the bottom of this answer.

If that does bother you, you can perform some slight optimizations:

1. Pretend the character a is 'a' and the x is 0. Now you start the string with "a" and are about to go on when really, the presence of that one 'a' already breaks the rule. But you still go on the calculate 26^6 more possibilites of the other six letters only to have them all rejected by the check function, meaning you wasted most of your time on pointless runs. We can do that by integrating the check function into the DFS and declaring the counters as global variables:
2. Preprocess what value of i added to the character 'a' will be that limited character a and b. That way, you won't have to calculate like this: `if ('a' + i == a || 'a' + i == b)`. You will be able to do `if (i == iofA || i == iofB)` to remove the unneccesary need to calculate the '+' sign.
3. Scrap the check function. As it is already integrated, you can also directly output each result string when currentIndex is greater than 6.

In summary, plugging in all the suggestions gives this entire code better timing than the old one. This can be seen by just entering this input for both versions:

```
a 0 b 0
```

And you will see the tremendous delay difference between the modified and optimized version with the optimized jumping straight to "c"s while the old slow version is stuck with no sign of output for a good long while because it is processing the unnecessary 'a' and 'b'.

However, don't get your hopes too high. The tremendous amount of output comes at a significant cost. Millions of lines might still take minutes or even hours to finish. I just shortened the time between the outputs so that you would get much less delay between them.

Here is another [online demo 2](https://onlinegdb.com/1VKIcNvtf), or see the new code below the old code:

**The old code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
char char1, char2;
int int1, int2;
bool checkString(std::string str, char a, char b, int x, int y) { // all parameters
    int numOfA = 0, numOfB = 0; //initialize counters
    for (char x : str) { // start a loop
        if (x == a) { numOfA++; } // increment accordingly
        else if (x == b) { numOfB++; } // increment accordingly
    }
    if (numOfA > x || numOfB > y) { return false; } // if too many letters of a or b, return false
    return true;
}
void dfs(int currentIndex, std::string currentString) { // new function
    if (currentIndex > 6) { // if string is complete, decide whether or not to output it
        if (checkString(currentString, char1, char2, int1, int2)) {
            std::cout << currentString << '\n'; // careful: this is hundreds of millions of lines of all possible strings derived from the original total of 26^7, or 8,031,810,176 after shaving off some with the check function
        }
        return; // no more processing
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { // run all possible characters
        currentString[currentIndex] = ((char) ('a' + i));
        dfs(currentIndex + 1, currentString); // next round
    }
}
int main() {
    std::cin >> char1 >> int1 >> char2 >> int2;
    dfs(0, "-------");
    return 0;
}
```

**The new code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
char char1, char2; // create limits
int int1, int2; //create limits
int numOfA = 0, numOfB = 0; //initialize counters;
int iofA, iofB;
void dfs(int currentIndex, std::string currentString) { // new function
    if (currentIndex > 6) { // you can directly output now
        std::cout << currentString << '\n';
        return; // no more processing
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        currentString[currentIndex] = ((char) ('a' + i));
        if (i == iofA) {
            if (++numOfA > int1) { numOfA--; } // ++numOfA adds 1 to numOfA before it processes the inequality evaluation because we already had the line "currentString[currentIndex] = ((char) ('a' + i));" before
            else {
                dfs(currentIndex + 1, currentString);
                iofA--; // restore before going to next letter as the current index will change as i increments
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if (i == iofB) {
            if (++numOfB > int2) { numOfB--; } // ++numOfB adds 1 to numOfB before it processes the inequality evaluation because we already had the line "currentString[currentIndex] = ((char) ('a' + i));" before
            else {
                dfs(currentIndex + 1, currentString);
                iofB--; // restore before going to next letter as the current index will change as i increments
            }
            continue;
        }
        dfs(currentIndex + 1, currentString); // next round
    }
}
int main() {
    std::cin >> char1 >> int1 >> char2 >> int2; // input
    iofA = ((int) (char1 - 'a')), iofB = ((int) (char2 - 'a')); // preprocess
    dfs(0, "-------"); // start dfs
    return 0;
}
```